# SignalR Hub Objects Reset

Tags: c#, signalr

I have some thing like that in my hub class:

```
private static List<message> messages = new List<message>();
```

the messages list is updating by the way.
but every 10-15 hours the messages list resets. so that messages.Count == 0.
why it happens ? 
should i update the messages stat in database ?

edit:

what about objects that handle some thing like player game positions that updates every 0.1sec.
what multiplayer servers do for this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static members like that are cleared during an IIS app pool reset. This happens (by default) every 12 hours.

Yes, you should store anything critical in a database.

Comment: @FARHADAFSAR Not having written one I can't be sure; but I would guess  they persist game state ever couple seconds, or use something like a Redis cache that won't be subject to IIS app pool resets but can still be written to extremely quickly.The #1 rule of cloud programming though is that you can't rely on the server always running; *never* rely on in-memory state